# How to correctly model given action with rich model approach, DDD and ruby

Tags: ruby, domain-driven-design

I'm working on my pet project where I have the following scenario:

- user can create article and becomes its owner
- only article owner can edit given article

I wonder how to model it correctly. I don't want to have dumb objects like `User` and `Article` that only have properties, but would like them to have some behavior. This is how I'd approach it initially:

```
article = articles_repository.find(id)
if(article.changeable_by(user))
  article.change(title, content)
  articles_repository.save(article)
else 
  raise NoEditRights
end
```

My only concern here is that I need to check if user can modify before I do modifications. I 
Another approach was to pass current user to `change` method and let `article` check it and raise error if user is not allowed to change it.

I was also thinking about something like this:

```
article = articles_repository.find(id)
article.as_user(user) do 
  article.change(title, content)
  articles_repository.save(article)
end
```

but I don't know if it is any better.

How would you approach such case? How to internally prevent article from being changed by other users I know it is quite simple, but I'd like to grasp how to model such cases before I jump into something more difficult.

**EDIT: some more info added**

So this is content publishing application, users can write and publish articles, others can read them and comment on them.

This is really simple app (just a toy project) and I can see the following bounded contexts here:

- publishing article
- editing article
- some others that are not important I guess (like comment on article)

I'm not sure if I should introduce different models for each context?

Comment: Both samples you provided might be pretty fine or terribly wrong. It depends on one question: what exactly your domain is and what bounded context it contains? Tell us more about it, then I could add my view on the design.

Comment: Added some more info, but don't know if it's enough

Answer (score 1):

These are not bounded context, but some use cases.

From what you say I guess there will be 2 bounded contexts: **publishing** and **access management**. Access management - unless you're willing to introduce some unordinary mechanisms - is a generic concern that probably don't require your focus and DDD - just add some good library that solves this problem already. And maybe wrap it with some application service.

So in some app service there would be a method doing something like (pseudocode, sorry, I don't know Ruby):

```
var user = auth::authenticationService.getUser(...)
if user.hasAccessTo(articleId) then
    var article = pub::articleRepo.get(articleId)
    article.doSomething()
end
```

Note that authentication service and user belongs to one context (auth) and article and article repo to another (pub). There is only a small connection between them. User don't know anything about articles in pub context (it's just a value object storing the id) and article doesn't know anything about access management (but probably has a value object of user that contains his name).

Another way would introduce some tiny objects in pub context like Author, Editor, Commenter representing the roles over the article.

```
var role = pub::roleService.getAuthorFor(articleId, userId)
if role != null then
    role.doSomethingWithArticle()
end
```

where roleService acts as an anticorruption layer between auth and pub (so it calls a authenticationService, gets user object full of auth-specific stuff and based on it, construct a lightweight role object that contains only pub-specific behavior.

The second example sounds heavier but it's more prone to changes in one of the contexts.